# How can you completely remove HTML tags containing a class in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, data-preprocessing

I have a web scraper that pulls articles from CNN, FOX, and BBC in BeautifulSoup.  Then after some preprocessing, I return raw articles to an API.  However, I cannot figure out how to completely remove HTML tags that contain an annoying class in Python.  I tried lxml cleaner but and I can remove tags, but not only the tags which contain a certain class.

If in this example I am trying to remove "help", I would like a script that would turn HTML that looks like this:

```
<p class="help">Here are some tips which are useful</p>
<p> Welcome to webscraping 101 </p>
<p class="help>These are the tips </p>
```

into this:

```
<p> Welcome to webscraping 101 </p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove all tags under the `help` class, you can use the [`.decompose()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) method:

> removes a tag from the tree, then completely destroys it and its
> contents

```
for tag in soup.find_all("p", class_="help"):
    tag.decompose()

print(soup.prettify())
```